# Set font styles in body tag, doesn't apply to tables

Tags: css, fonts

How can I set font styles in css for the whole page? I set them for `body {...}` but it doesn't apply it to the tables in my page.

Answer (score 2):

In [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html) in some browsers, and in *very* old browsers, tables do not inherit some properties that they should inherit by the spec. So it looks like your pages are treated in Quirks Mode. Changing this by adding `<!doctype html>` at the start would be easy, but it could cause almost anything else, too.

The simplest way to handle this is to set the font properties on tables, too, e.g.

```
body, table { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
body { font-size: 85%; }
table { font-size: 100%; }
```

To set font styles for the whole page, on *all* elements, use the universal selector `*`, e.g.

```
* { font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 100%; }
```

(Some elements, like `input` and `pre`, have their own default font settings as per browser defaults, so inheritance does not apply to them.)

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    font-family: /*what ever */;
}
```

**Some browsers do not inherit `font properties`  into table cells correctly.**

so you can try

```
body, table, td {
    font-family:/*what ever*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html{font-size:20px;}
```

you can try this one.

Answer (score 0):

It includes tables automatically, if not set specifically somewhere more precise (for example with another element, class or id).

You can try to use a reset css file to reset all standard fonts and styles. [Html5Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) have a really good one, or you can try to be more specific:

```
body, table, td {
    font: san-serif;
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the reset. I use http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ and it's also quite good.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
* {font-style:normal;}
```

Although I think you mean "font-family", since you only have three choices for font-style-- bold, italic, and normal, and having an entire page one style would be tough on the eyes..... If that's the case, here is the font-family example:

try

```
* {font-family:verdana;}
```

or

body {font-family:yourstyle;}

You should see changes throughout the whole page.